# Is there a way to set a cap (maximum participant) number within the price set field?

Tags: civievent

I was hoping to find out if there was a way to set a cap on the price set field rather than the event. For our summer camp, we have a morning and afternoon session that you register for under the same event, but can pay which session you want. We were wanting to set a cap on both the morning and afternoon session. Since they aren't their own event, I didn't know if this was possible.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. In your Price Field Option on a checkbox field type you should see 'max participants' field so you can limit how many can sign up to any option. Just make it a $0 item if you need to have it as a 'free' option within a paid event.

[image]