# Is there a way to set maximum participants combining several price fields?

Tags: civievent, price-sets

Continuing on from [this question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18682/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-cap-maximum-participant-number-within-the-price-set-fi?rq=1), is there any way to accumulate max participants across several price set fields?

Eg, we often have weekend events in which people can enroll with a weekend price for both days, or alternatively, they can enroll for either Saturday or Sunday. It's common for Saturday and Sunday to have different prices.

We want the total of (Weekend + Saturday) or (Weekend + Sunday) to be within the total venue capacity.

If my understanding is correct, we can't use the overall 'Max Number of Participants' from Event settings, because this will always combine Weekend + Saturday + Sunday.

Any ideas on how to move forward on this?